# What does 'inject' do?

Tags: python, ruby, pseudocode

I've been translating some Ruby code to Python but this has me stumped.

Could somebody please break down what this `inject` function is doing?

```
val = (0..seq.size - 2).inject(1.0) do |v, i|
  v * rates[seq[i]][seq[i+1]]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudocode, given a 2D array "rates" and a single array "seq":

```
val = 1.0
for each consecutive pair(s,t) of values in seq:
    val = product * rates[s][t]
```

So if `seq = [1,2,3]`, this gives the product `rates[1][2] * rates[2][3]`

In python:

```
val = 1.0
for i in range(len(seq)-1):
     val*=rates[seq[i]][seq[i+1]]
```

or

```
reduce(lambda v,i: v*rates[seq[i]][seq[i+1]], range(len(seq)-1), 1.0)
```

Comment: Why python when the question is clearly tagged `ruby`?

Comment: A misguided question editor removed the code which says "I've been translating Ruby to Python..."   I'm reverting the edit.

Comment: Very well I have additionally added the [tag:python] tag too

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to

```
val = 1.0
(0..seq.size - 2).each do |i|
    val = val * rates[seq[i]][seq[i+1]]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`inject` is an "accumulator" method in Ruby. If you hear this word for first time, you can take a look at this [article](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/Functions/TheAccumulatorPattern.html). Here is the [API doc](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) for the method. Also an [alias method](https://wikimatze.de/method-alias-in-ruby/) of `inject` is `reduce` - depending on the context in which you use it, your code may become more readable and meaningful.

In your example the `1.0` value is just the start value for the method to accumulate on. If for example your `seq` has a length of 3 (`[1,2,3]`), your loop will execute the following steps:

1. `1.0 *= rates[1][2]             #=> i = 0`
2. `1.0*rates[1][2] *= rates[2][3] #=> i = 1 = seq.size - 2`

At the end the loop will return the accumulated `val` variable.